# Show top n most active committers in a git repository

Tags: git

I use `git shortlog -s -n --all` to show all the contributors in a git repository.

```
 18756  Someone   
  6604  Someone Else  
  6025  Etc     
  5503  Another Committer     
  5217  And So On
```

I wonder if there is an option to show first *n* contributors. For example:

```
git shortlog -s -n --all --some-option 3
```

And the output will be:

```
18756  Someone   
 6604  Someone Else  
 6025  Etc
```

A solution would be use Unix pipes and `head`:

```
git shortlog -s -n --all | head -3
```

...but if there is a built-in

Comment: According to the [`git-shortlog` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog), the command offers no such option, and I can't think of an easy alternative to your current approach. Don't feel bad about using pipes `:)`

Comment: @Jubobs I'm not sure if using pipes works cross platform. However, I realize now that `git shortlog -s -n --all --max-count 3` shows the first 3 least active users. :)

Comment: I cannot replicate the behavior you describe. For instance, if I run that command in the Git-project's repo, I only get `3 Junio Hamano`, whereas Junio is the most prolific contributor to the project in terms of number of commits. I don't think `--max-count` is meant to be used with `git shortlog`, even though that flag doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @Jubobs You're very correct. I guess the `max-count` tells to `shortlog` how many commits to parse or so.

Comment: What I was searching for is already in the question body, so  I don't need answers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a way of doing this with the native `git shortlog` command. It's usually used to generate a contributors list between releases rather than a *top n* statistic.

Your approach of using pipes is likely to be the most efficient way of solving the problem; you could also use a script or git alias to do the same thing.